# Field text not getting translated sometimes

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

As in the image(of German node), I'm outputting a text link in English: "Report an Issue" using Computed Field module so it looks like: `$text = t("Report an Issue");` in the php code.

I've then translated it by going to admin/config/regional/translate/translate in all supported languages.

The problem is that sometimes I see the English version: "Report an Issue" in the non-English nodes. Many times it looks fine. But when I clear all caches, it shows fine. While all the node title, fields, labels show correct translation only except this field. The url is see is mysite.com/de/title which is as expected.

I'm only using i18n and not Entity Translation.

**What could be the problem?**

[image: After all cache clear this field always show correctly]

Comment: After clear all cache it work correctly but later get return to english version in non-english node?

Comment: @zhilevan Yes it shows correctly for the current node but for any other non-English node it may not.

Comment: What do you have in admin/config/regional/language/configure?

Comment: First is URL, then User then Session.

Comment: @Gisle Hannemyr it was in English then I installed i18n and enabled 8 languages(German,French,Russian,Chinese,Japanese etc)